# Issue with loading startup programs for different Windows 10 users - errors when switching to a different account

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I currently have 2 separate Windows 10 accounts on my PC - one for me and one for my son.

When I start Windows using my account, I run 3 programs on Startup - PowerMate.exe, Volume2.exe and Pianoteq 7.exe , by putting their shortcuts into the Startup Folder.

PowerMate.exe - controls my Griffin volume knob
Volume2.exe - controls an on screen volume display
Pianoteq 7.exe - a software piano

So far everything works normally.

However, when my son uses his account to logon, these programs don't work anymore - Windows seems to be loading another instance of these 3 programs when he logs on, which causes a conflict in their processes. (I notice 2 instances of PowerMate.exe , Volume2.exe and Pianoteq 7.exe in Task Manager)

The programs no longer work. I have to manually kill off all these processes in Task Manager, and click their shortcuts individually to get them to work again.

Is there away I can configure windows to, upon logon to any of my 2 accounts - looks for these 3 processes in task manager and kill/ shut them off AND THEN load these 3 programs?

Or perhaps some other easier way to get this to work?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the programs into the Startup folder, use a `.bat`
script file.

The script might look like (untested by me):

```
taskkill /IM PowerMate.exe
taskkill /IM Volume2.exe
taskkill /IM "Pianoteq 7.exe"
start "" "C:\path\to\PowerMate.exe"
start "" "C:\path\to\Volume2.exe"
start "" "C:\path\to\Pianoteq 7.exe"
```

For more information about using the above programs, use in a Command Prompt
the `/?` parameter like this: `taskkill /?`.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly. I put this file into a folder and then created a shortcut, and dropped the shortcut into the Startup Folder. I then used the Run As Administrator under the Shortcut's property which made everything run perfectly.

Comment: However one small issue arose - when I am in my son's account the bat file runs and the programs start automatically, but when I come back into my own account the processes have been taskilled, and I have to click the .cmd file manually. 

Is there a way that the shortcut can run everytime I change accounts? 


If not I think I can still live with it, I will just click this file when i switch accounts - it's already so much better than having to click all 3 programs individually. 


Once again, thanks so much!!